# Transform / Rotate QGraphicsItem w/ animation Qt, C++

Tags: c++, linux, qt

Currently i try to animate a `QGraphicsItem` at his `Qt::YAxis`.
I have this example code here but it does not work, cause the `QGraphicsPixmapItem` not have an property "*transform*".

```
QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation(myQGraphPixItem, "transform");
animation->setDuration(10000);
animation->setStartValue(QTransform::rotate (0, Qt::YAxis));
animation->setEndValue(QTransform::rotate (60, Qt::YAxis));

animation->start();
```

So how i can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Declare you own transform property

```
class YourItem : public QGraphicsPixmapItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QTransform transfrom READ transform WRITE setTransform)
    ...
};
```

Comment: but i cant make an animation so?

Answer (score 0):

QTransform is currently not supported in QVariantAnimation. take a look at 
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qvariantanimation.html#details